# Passing data in an event - dos and don'ts

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm a little confused on passing data in events. I'm getting inconsistent results, and I'd like to understand why `$(this).val()` does not get passed, but if I declare it prior it does. I understand why the last method works, but not why it returns nothing/undefined. Can someone help clear this up for me?

**Edit:** the `obj` is `<input id="test" value="myvalue" type="text">`

```
obj = $('#test');

tellme = function(data){
  alert(data);
}
obj.on('click',function(e){ tellme($(this).val()) }); //How I usually pass things

tellmeagain = function(event){
  alert(event.data.val);
}
obj.on('click',{val:'test'},tellmeagain); //works
obj.on('click',{val:this.value},tellmeagain); //undefined
obj.on('click',{val:$(this).val()},tellmeagain); //returns nothing

value = obj.val()
obj.on('click',{val:value},tellmeagain); //works
```

[Fiddle of code.](http://jsfiddle.net/pC6s5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with those expressions

```
obj.on('click',{val:this.value},tellmeagain); //undefined
obj.on('click',{val:$(this).val()},tellmeagain); //returns nothing
```

is that `this.value` and `$(this).val()` are computed **at binding time**, not when the event occurs. Not only has the value not changed but `this` isn't even your element (it might be `window` if your code is in the global scope or in a `$.ready` callback as in your fiddle).

To make it more clear, this line

```
obj.on('click',{val:this.value},tellmeagain); //undefined
```

is equivalent to

```
var rhfle = {val:this.value}; // what do you think is this ? it's window
obj.on('click',rhfle,tellmeagain);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why is `$(this)||this` not my element? It reports the value using the 1st function.

Comment: Because in the scope where you write `{val:this.value}`, `this` has no reason to be your element. What it is, we can't tell from the code you show.

Comment: Ah, check the fiddle I included in the OP. It's an input.

Comment: @kcdwayne In the fiddle, `this`, in the most external visible scope, **isn't** an input. It's `window`.

Comment: Ah, ok I see! `this`=`window`, therefor it doesn't even know about `obj`. Which is the lesser of two evils? Setting it up with `event.data.foo` or just using an anonymous function to retrieve it? Both seem more entailed than I would like, but I'm leaning toward the latter to keep the base function more simple.

Comment: Passing a `data` object isn't so common, as it's usually easy to get what you need from the callback or using a closure.

Answer (score 0):

simply because the value comes from the "obj" instead of "this"

```
value = obj.val()

this.value  ?????
```